# Laravel Pivot relations

Tags: laravel, pivot, relationship

I have `Booking`, `Status` and `User` models. I also have a pivot table `booking_status` with extra column `created_by` to keep track of who changed that status of the booking.

So how can I get user info when I access booking statuses:

```
$booking = App\Booking::first();

$statuses = $booking->history_statuses;
```

So when I loop through those `statuses` in the view I would like to retrieve the name of the user. How is it done?

I know that I can access that field like

```
$status->pivot->created_by
```

But then I get an ID of the user and it doesn't feel correct to fetch the user by id in the view for every status.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships
At what point there are issues?

Comment: Could you please share all your models?

Answer (score 1):

In your Relationship use

```
public function booking_status(){
    return $this->hasMany(booking_status::class)->withPivot('created_by');
}
```

Then you can simply access using

```
$booking = App\Booking::first();

$statuses = $booking->history_statuses;

foreach($statuses as $status){

   $status->pivot->created_by // this is your element

}
```

Comment: I came up with that already, but then I simply get an ID of the user. And if I loop through the statuses in the view to show the history of status changes, I find it wrong if in the view I would look for the user by id every time... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a many to many relationship from booking to status. and now you want to create a relation from the pivot to the user.
I was looking at this yesterday for 2 hours.
The solution i came up with was to go from booking to the pivot and the go on to the status.
Something like this should work

## booking model

```
public function booking_status(){
    return $this->hasMany(booking_status::class);
}
```

## booking_status model

```
public function status(){
    return $this->belongsTo(status::class);
} 
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(status::class);
}
```

## user model

```
public function booking_status(){
    return $this->hasMany(booking_status::class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought of something like that, but it felt like there must be a more sophisticated and elegant way that I am not aware of :)

Comment: after 2 or 3 hours of trying creating a relationship to the pivot table and to access that relation i gave up and settled for this monstrosity...

Comment: well, at least now I know I am not the only one :D promise to share, if I come across that  better solution :)

Comment: but.. what if we used [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)? then we could maybe do what i did above but more elegant as in `public function user(){return $this->hasManyThrough('user','booking_status');}`  i haven't tested this but looks promising